# How do I create the same function (html input to jsp) using prolog

Tags: jsp, prolog

I am doing program that use prolog to be integrated with HTML and currently stuck at understanding HTTPSESSION in prolog and want to create same function as the JSP below.

HTML input from user:

```
`<form action="page2.jsp" method="post">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="patientname" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>`
```

JSP taking input from HTML:

```
`<%
String name = request.getParameter("patientname");
 session.setAttribute("patientname", name);
%>`
```

anyone can help? I already seen the http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=httpsession but still cant understand how to implement the code in prolog.

Comment: I think basically you want to do something like `http_session_asserta(patientname(Name))` to add that fact to the session. Later you'd obtain it with `http_session_data(patientname(Name))` to unify `Name` with the current session's patient name.

Comment: I believe you can obtain the form value with something like `http_parameters(Request, _, [form_data(Values)]), member(patientname=PatientName, Values).`

Comment: what is difference between http_session_asserta() and http_session_assert(). Now I am having difficulities due to whenever I submit a new form the parameters I call and http_session_data() will replaced my old data .I dont want my I old data to be replaced.

Comment: It's the same as `asserta/1` and `assert/1`. The former is standard, because you can assert multiple facts with the same arity into the database, the `a` suffix says "at the beginning of the database" (i.e. before the other facts you already have) versus `z` meaning "at the end" (i.e. after the others). I generally avoid `assert/1` because it is non-standard and leaves the question open. If you don't want your old data replaced, check for it before asserting it. That's just programming.

Comment: `page_content(Request) -->
 {
  http_parameters(Request,[patient(Patient,[optional(true)])]),
  http_session_asserta(-Patient)
 },` Here I had insert first form value to the asserta/1 in next_page.pl and later I insert second form value to the asserta/1 in next_page2.pl 
    `page_content(Request) -->
 {
  http_parameters(Request,[age(Age,[optional(true)])]),
  http_session_asserta(-Age),
  http_session_data(Patient)
 },`.When I had enter new value to asserta/1 the value will read the age value instead. Or is it another way I can use http_session_data() to get both value.

Comment: Use `http_session_data(patient(Patient))` to obtain it. Condition on that and use `http_session_asserta` if you don't have it.

Comment: where should I put this `http_session_data(patient(Patient))` cause when I run the server the output was blank page(error) and how do I call the value from `http_session_data(patient(Patient))` inside HTML. I use `-Patient` to call but no value appear in HTML.

Comment: already tried one more times and its work thank you !!

Answer (score -1):

A session object is specific to the JavaServer Pages
Specification Version 2.0, it has the following API:

> **public abstract javax.servlet.http.HttpSession getSession()**
>   The current value of the session object (an HttpSession).
>   Returns: the HttpSession for this PageContext or null

So as long as you don't use a container that implements the JSP API, everything might look different. The SWI-Prolog provides its own container API, and session data seems to be hold in:

```
:- dynamic session_data/2.
```

Which you can access and modify through the `http_session_XXX` predicates. An alternative would be to use a Java based Prolog and directly run inside a Container that implements the JSP API, such as for example Tomcat.

The later approach would have the advantage that you can mix Java and Prolog freely. Means you can still write dynamic pages in JSP, and here and then use Prolog for some tasks.

The later is for example possible in Jekejeke Prolog, see also this tutorial here, which shows how to develop a forms JSP application that runs inside Tomcat and that uses both Java and Prolog:

**Jekejeke Prolog - Servlet Deployment**
http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/05_run/15_stdy/08_deploy/07_servlet/package.html